# Print screen types S

Tags: 22.04, print-screen

I have an issue where the Print Screen button types the letter "S" and the settings button types the letter "i". I haven't seen anyone else with this issue. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you mention which keyboard layout you are using??

Comment: @Ajay I have a Lenovo Ideapad 5 14ARE05